# How to join two DataFrames in Scala and Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There are two DataFrames (Scala, Apache Spark 1.6.1)

1) Matches

```
         MatchID | Player1    |  Player2 
         --------------------------------
               1 | John Wayne | John Doe
               2 | Ive Fish   | San Simon
```

2) Personal Data

```
              Player     |  BirthYear 
              --------------------------------
              John Wayne | 1986
              Ive Fish   | 1990
              San Simon  | 1974
              john Doe   | 1995
```

How could create a new DataFrame with 'BirthYear' for the both players

```
         MatchID | Player1    |  Player2  | BYear_P1 |BYear_P2 | Diff
         -------------------------------------------------------------
               1 | John Wayne | John Doe  |   1986   | 1995    |  9  
               2 | Ive Fish   | San Simon |   1990   | 1974    |  16
```

?

I tried

```
    val df = MatchesDF.join(PersonalDF, MatchesDF("Player1") === PersonalDF("Player"))
```

then join again for the second player

```
    val resDf = df.join(PersonalDF, df("Player2") === PersonalDF("Player"))
```

but it's VERY time consuming operation.

May be another way to do it in Scala and Apache Spark?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should perform better:

```
case class Match(matchId: Int, player1: String, player2: String)
case class Player(name: String, birthYear: Int)

val matches = Seq(
  Match(1, "John Wayne", "John Doe"),
  Match(2, "Ive Fish", "San Simon")
)

val players = Seq(
  Player("John Wayne", 1986),
  Player("Ive Fish", 1990),
  Player("San Simon", 1974),
  Player("John Doe", 1995)
)

val matchesDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(matches)
val playersDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(players)

matchesDf.registerTempTable("matches")
playersDf.registerTempTable("players")

sqlContext.sql(
  "select matchId, player1, player2, p1.birthYear, p2.birthYear, abs(p1.birthYear-p2.birthYear) " +
  "from matches m inner join  players p1 inner join players p2 " +
  "where m.player1 = p1.name and m.player2 = p2.name").show()

+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---+
|matchId|   player1|  player2|birthYear|birthYear|_c5|
+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---+
|      1|John Wayne| John Doe|     1986|     1995|  9|
|      2|  Ive Fish|San Simon|     1990|     1974| 16|
+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---+
```

I didn't find the way to express join of 3 tables in Scala DSL.

Comment: again doing two joins, how does it make it better?

Comment: This run about 2 minutes for Matches table with  ~10000 rows and 
Player table with ~700 records

Comment: use data frames for your joins instead of plain sql for better performance.

Comment: @dheee Facing similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149483/outer-join-on-2-data-frames-spark-scala-sqlcontext  Any idea ?

Comment: if you have more than 2 DataFrame you want to do join on. Would it be faster to do it in one query or several join / select ?

Answer (score 26):

This is a solution using spark's dataframe functions:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs

val matches = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Row(1, "John Wayne", "John Doe"), Row(2, "Ive Fish", "San Simon")))

val players = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  Row("John Wayne", 1986),
  Row("Ive Fish", 1990),
  Row("San Simon", 1974),
  Row("John Doe", 1995)
))

val matchesDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(matches, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("matchId", IntegerType, nullable = false),
  StructField("player1", StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("player2", StringType, nullable = false)))
).as('matches)

val playersDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(players, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("player", StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("birthYear", IntegerType, nullable = false)
))).as('players)

matchesDf
  .join(playersDf, $"matches.player1" === $"players.player")
  .select($"matches.matchId" as "matchId", $"matches.player1" as "player1", $"matches.player2" as "player2", $"players.birthYear" as "player1BirthYear")
  .join(playersDf, $"player2" === $"players.player")
  .select($"matchId" as "MatchID", $"player1" as "Player1", $"player2" as "Player2", $"player1BirthYear" as "BYear_P1", $"players.birthYear" as "BYear_P2")
  .withColumn("Diff", abs('BYear_P2.minus('BYear_P1)))
  .show()

+-------+----------+---------+--------+--------+----+
|MatchID|   Player1|  Player2|BYear_P1|BYear_P2|Diff|
+-------+----------+---------+--------+--------+----+
|      1|John Wayne| John Doe|    1986|    1995|   9|
|      2|  Ive Fish|San Simon|    1990|    1974|  16|
+-------+----------+---------+--------+--------+----+
```

Comment: I like that you completely prevented SQL statements! +1

Answer (score 4):

In Spark 2.0 and above, Spark provides several syntaxes to join two dataframes

```
join(right: Dataset[_]): DataFrame
join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumn: String): DataFrame
join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame
join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String], joinType: String): DataFrame
join(right: Dataset[_], joinExprs: Column): DataFrame
join(right: Dataset[_], joinExprs: Column, joinType: String): DataFrame
```

All these [Spark Join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/) methods available in the Dataset class and these methods return DataFrame (note DataFrame = Dataset[Row])

All these methods take first arguments as a Dataset[_] meaning it also takes DataFrame.

To explain how to join, I will take emp and dept DataFrame

```
empDF.join(deptDF,empDF("emp_dept_id") ===  deptDF("dept_id"),"inner")
    .show(false)
```

If you have to join column names the same on both dataframes, you can even ignore join expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
val df = left.join(right, Seq("name"))
display(df)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer so it becomes more valuable for other users. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This information is insufficient to provide any sort of help. What is "left"? What is "right"? Please rephrase your answer..

Comment: There's no such function as display in Spark Dataframe (Scala implementation)

Comment: I do like the syntax of using `Seq("column_name")` as the join condition, its what my colleagues all use and its readable.  For explanation: I think `left` is one dataframe and `right` is one dataframe - so this is not a left-join or right-join situation.