# How to join multiple dataFrames in spark with different column names and types without converting into RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

My df1 has column of type Double, df2 has column of type Timestamp and df3 has column of type Integer.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
df1 = ...
df2 = ...
df3 = ...
val df4 = df1.zip(df2).zip(df3)
```

However there's no such function like "zip". How can I archive such result?

Comment: What have you tried? It's a one minute reading to find necessary function in documentation or in IDE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two DataFrames in Scala and Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800174/how-to-join-two-dataframes-in-scala-and-apache-spark)

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is not always a duplicate. That's why you have information about close vote and you can say why it is not a duplicate

Comment: my question is simple. If I have let's say 3 data frames with different column names and different column types and no data frame have same column name or value. I just want to simply zip these 3 data frames into one so that the final data frame will contain columns and their values of those 3 data frames.

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit zip for DataFrames. You can do workaround:

```
val df1Ordered = df1.withColumn("rowNr", row_number().over(Window.orderBy('someColumn));
// the same for other DataFrames
// now join those DataFrames

val newDF = df1Ordered.join(df2Ordered, "rowNr").join("df3Ordered", "rowNr")
```

However it will be quite slow, because there is no `partitionBy` in Window operation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But This work around I already have in my list if nothing will work.

Comment: Why down vote? It will work, even author said that. It's slow, but I also wrote it

Comment: It's not me, maybe the one who has downvoted my question, did this.

Comment: I really don't like it. How can I approve my question if I have no feedback? Nevermind, @NamanAgarwal I will keep my answer, maybe someone will use it in the future ;)