# How to create a dataframe from two others dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have these two dataframe objects, with a single column each:

```
a = predictons_lr.select('prediction')
b = predictions_nb.select('prediction')
```

I would like to create a single resulting dataframe having `a` and `b` as columns.
I have tried:

```
df_result = spark.createDataFrame([a, b])
```

but I get this error:

> AssertionError: dataType py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x000002260F3D4240 should be an instance of class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'

There is an efficient method to create a dataframe of this kind?

Comment: Do any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36808120/11639518) fit the bill? They all seem to be getting after the joining of dataframes, which looks like the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this two column are same data type , you can just union

```py
a = predictons_lr.select('prediction')
b = predictions_nb.select('prediction')

new_df = a.union(b)
```

Comment: I would a resulting dataframe having two distinct columns. Your method gives in output a single "joined" column.

Comment: If you need two distinct columns, what's your join key ?

Comment: I am only trying to create a dataframe with two columns, in which each of these is a single column dataframe: `a` and `b`. I don't want to join these columns.

Comment: If sequence doesn't matter, unless to columns are same size, and , you still need to deal with null