# How to properly create a new dataframe using PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create a data frame ,using `PySpark,` by:

```
lr_col = predictions_lr.select('prediction_1')
nb_col = predictions_nb.select('prediction_2')
df = spark.createDataFrame([lr_col, nb_col])
```

but, when I run the code above, I get this error:

> AssertionError: dataType py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x00000237C7D2B550 should be an instance of class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'

How could I convert my data in the requested data type?

Comment: What are `lr_col` and `nb_col`?

Comment: Single column datasets.

Comment: I mean, what *type* of object are they?

Comment: They are float.

Comment: I don't mean what type of object they *contain*. What does `print(type(lr_col))` give you?

Comment: They are <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

Comment: So what you actually want is to *combine* two DataFrames. Do they have the same columns (you want to combine their rows), or do they share a common column you can join on (you want to combine their columns)?

Comment: I would like to create a new dataframe with two columns: 'predictions' and 'predictions'. If necessary, I can rename the two columns, ad example 'pred_1' and 'pred_2'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dataframe from two others dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676494/how-to-create-a-dataframe-from-two-others-dataframe). Don't repost the *exact* same question again. If the previous one was poorly received, you need to edit it to make it clearer. What you're asking for can not generally be done because Spark Dataframes are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

You add a uid for each prediction in each of the two DataFrame's, and then simply inner join the two DataFrame's on this `id`.

```py
predictions_lr.join(predictions_nb, 'id')
```